# why i can't edit the maven index.html in the target directory

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I tried to edit my index.html file in my target directory. For an unknown reason, after the editing, it switches back to it's old version.

Answer (score 1):

The target directory is the default output directory for Maven projects.  If you are trying to edit a file, edit it from within the src directory.  As soon as you clean, compile, install, etc the target directory will be overwritten with the latest output.

edit: are you sure you are editing the right file?  Maybe you should be editing index.apt?
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html

Comment: First of all, thank you. Even when I copy the file in my src directory, nothing happens...

Comment: @julschi I'm not familiar with site plugin specifically, but I found some docs that maybe helpful and edited my answer